# Magento 2 : Get value of custom option

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, magento2.3.2

I have a custom option of product
[image]

How can I get value: 20, 30 in .phtml file. Hope anyone helps me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get custom option value

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

if (empty($customOptions)) { //check if product has custom options. If it doesn't go to the next product
    continue; }

foreach($customOptions as $option) {
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { //check if option has values (Option can have values only if option type is checkbox, radio, multiselect or drop-down)
        continue;
    }

    foreach($values as $value) {
        $valueData = $value->getData(); //do whatever you want will value data
    } }
```

To get custom option value title use this:

```
foreach($customOptions as $option) {
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { //check if option has values (Option can have values only if option type is checkbox, radio, multiselect or drop-down)
        continue;
    }

    foreach($values as $value) {
        $valueTitle = $value->getTitle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for answer. How can I use it in my order information in admin https://prnt.sc/piarph